# Nav menu not opening beneath header for medium screens using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-4, nav

I am unable to make the nav menu load from the bottom when the browser screen is medium size.

On Firefox browser, when the hamburger icon is pressed, it should be loading beneath the header. It is appearing correctly when I make the width of the browser really small like this:

[image: correct for small screen]

But for some reason, when I start to increase the width, it loads the menu from the right hand side. Like this:

[image: incorrect for medium screen]

I attempted updating the CSS but to no effect.

Please find the code here and any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
https://www.codeply.com/go/qMkYwnOOrH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way you're using rows and cols, you need to change this div:

```
<div class="row no-gutters nav-item-container">
```

like this:

```
<div class="row no-gutters nav-item-container collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
```

and here delete the class and id attributes:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
```

Comment: Thank you @David IX! You just cured a major headache!